# Relationship between $p$-normed plane and Euclidean $3$-space

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, riemannian-geometry, curvature

This question arised from the comments on [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4463633/pi-4-relation-between-p-norms-and-the-hyperbolic-plane).

Let $(\Bbb R^2,d_p)$ be the Cartesian plane equipped with the $p$-*distance*, i.e., the distance given by

$$d_p(x,y):=(|x_1-y_1|^p+|x_2-y_2|^p)^{1/p},\qquad x,y\in\Bbb R^2,$$

where $p\ge2$, and let $(\Bbb R^3,d')$ be the Cartesian space equipped with the usual Euclidean distance,

$$d'(x,y):=(|x_1-y_1|^2+|x_2-y_2|^2+|x_3-y_3|^2)^{1/2},\qquad x,y\in\Bbb R^3.$$

**1.** If $p\ne2$, is it possible to define a smooth, isometrical embedding $e_p:(\Bbb R^2,d_p)\to(\Bbb R^3,d')$ ? Perhaps an immersion?

**2.** In either case, if the answer is *yes*, are there any constraints on the sectional curvature of the resulting submanifold $e(\Bbb R^2)\subset\Bbb R^3$ with respect to the Riemannian metric induced from the usual flat metric on $\Bbb R^3$ ?

**UPDATE**

Following the help from the comments below, I'll try to formulate the question in another way:

If $p>2$, is there a differentiable immersion $i:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3$ such that the pullback of the Riemannian metric induced on $i(\Bbb R^2)$ defines the $p$-distance, as described above, on $\Bbb R^2$ ?

Or even simpler:

If $p>2$, can the $p$-distance, as described above, be induced from a Riemannian metric on $\Bbb R^2$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "isometrical?" There are two possible notions of an isometric embedding here: One in the sense of metric geometry and the other in the sense of Finsler geometry.

Comment: @MoisheKohan My first goal was to understand if it's possible to make sense of a relationship between the $p$-normed plane, with $p>2$, and the hyperbolic plane. This goal was inspired by a property of circles. The way I formulated the original question was a bit messy. Thus, here I tried to elaborate another question in such simpler terms that it might more probably turn out to be a known fact. That's why I formulated it in terms of metric geometry. I believe an answer to this question will throw enough light on the original one. Although, a Finsler geometric approach will also be welcome.

Comment: I don’t see how it’s possible to do this. The metric space structure of any smoothly isometrically embedded submanifold has to be the one from the induced Riemannian metric.

Comment: A normed vector space $V$ admits an isometric embedding (in the sense of metric geometry) in a Euclidean (more generally, inner-product) space if and only if the norm on $V$ comes from an inner product on $V$. In the context of your question, it's if and only if $p=2$.

Comment: Okay, now I see why metric geometry isn't suited for the phenomenom I'm trying to grasp. Unfortunately I won't be able to keep thinking about it right now. =/

Comment: Actually, on second thought, I'll try to update the question just one more time.

Comment: The answers to your new questions are no and no. Given an isometry $f: M \rightarrow N$ and a unit ball $B \subset T_pM$, $f_*(B) \subset T_{f(p)}N$ has to be the intersection of a linear subspace with the unit ball in $T_{f(p)}N$. That's not possible if the unit ball in $M$ is the $p$-ball, with $p \ne 2$, and the unit ball in $N$ is the standard ball.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question in both versions is negative.

1. There is no immersion $i: R^2\to R^3$ such that the pull-back of the flat Riemannian metric on $R^3$ yields the flat Finsler metric on $R^2$ given by a $p$-norm, $p\ne 2$.

To understand this, you have to think through definitions. The pull-back of a Riemannian metric, in general, is again a Riemannian metric. This is simply because a pull-back at each point is essentially the restriction  of an inner product on $R^n$ to a linear subspace in $R^n$. But such a restriction is obviously again an inner product, hence, cannot be given by a norm which does not come from an inner product, such as a p-norm for $p\ne 2$.

2. Consider $R^m$ equipped with a p-norm ($p\ne 2$) and $R^n$ equipped with an inner product. Both define distance functions $d_p$ on $R^m, d_2$ on $R^n$. Then there is no isometric embedding $f: (R^m,d_p)\to (R^n,d_2)$, i.e. a map such that
   $$
   d_2(f(x), f(y))=d_p(x,y), \forall x, y\in R^m. 
   $$
   Proof. Suppose that such a map exists. Then it has to send geodesics to geodesics (shortest paths). Unless $p=1$ or $p=\infty$, any two points in $(R^m, d_p)$ are connected by a unique (up to a reparameterization) geodesic. If the case $p=1, \infty$ uniqueness fails, which is why there is no distance-preserving map  $f: (R^m,d_p)\to (R^n,d_2)$ in this case.
   Now, assume that $p\ne 1, \infty$. Then it is not hard to see that straight line segments are geodesics in $(R^m,d_p)$. Therefore, under a distance-preserving map $f$ they would go to straight line segments. Consider now a parallelogram $ABCD$ in  $ (R^m,d_p)$, in which we draw the two diagonals: Its image under $f$ would  have to be a parallelogram again since the diagonals  would map to intersecting line segments, forcing the image to be contained in a 2-dimensional affine plane in $R^n$. Now, I use the parallelogram law in $(R^n,d_2)$:
   $$
   2 ( d^2_2(f(A), f(B)) + d^2_2(f(B), f(C)))= d^2_2(f(A), f(C)) + d^2_2(f(B), f(D)). 
   $$
   Since $f$ is an isometric embedding, this forces the parallelogram law in $(R^m,d_p)$:
   $$
   2 ( d^2_p(A, B) + d^2_p(B, C))= d^2_p(A, C) + d^2_p(B, D). 
   $$
   But then this means that $d_p$ [comes from an inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#Normed_vector_spaces_satisfying_the_parallelogram_law) on $R^m$, implying that $p=2$.